# MinGW-w64 GDBServer: Assertion `find_thread_process (process) == NULL' failed

Tags: c++, remote-debugging, mingw-w64, gdbserver

I am trying to remotely debug a Windows application compiled with MinGW-w64 compiler from MSYS2.

```
dummy@KS-win10eng-dbg:/mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/bin$ ./gdbserver.exe --version
GNU gdbserver (GDB) 11.1
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
gdbserver is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.
This gdbserver was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32"

dummy@KS-win10eng-dbg:/mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/bin$ ./g++.exe --version
g++.exe (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

But the server constantlty crashes at random point of execution with the message:

```
dummy@KS-win10eng-dbg:/mnt/c/msys64/mingw64/bin$ $debug
Listening on port 1234
Remote debugging from host 10.251.74.23, port 58804
Detaching from process 4356
../../gdb-11.1t/erminate called without an active exception
gdbserver/inferiors.cc:159: A problem internal to GDBserver has been detected.
void remove_process(process_info*): Assertion `find_thread_process (process) == NULL' failed.
```

I tried building with:

- `g++.exe`
- `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`
- `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++-posix.exe`

What causes this?

---

The Server will crash even on a simple program with one breakpoint if you wait for some time:

```
int main()
{
    return 0; // breakpoint here
}
```

---

https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/924/ - I've opened a bug report

Comment: Does it also crash if you don't detach from the process?

Comment: @ssbssa I didn't do nothing. It just crashes. I am using CLion to run a remote debug session. I never used console commands for debugging.

Comment: Well, your output says `Detaching from process`.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure you can detach from a process with CLion as well (according to the [docu](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/attaching-to-local-process.html#detach-from-process), it's done with `Stop`).

Comment: @ssbssa and it wasn't a result of *any of my* actions. I set a breakpoint. When it is hit, I do nothing. Then the Server crashes with an error after some time. That's it. It doesn't happen when I remote debug an Ubuntu app with gcc GDB Server

Comment: The real reason should be in GDB 11.1 source code in file `gdbserver/inferiors.cc` around line 159. But instead of debugging the debugger, you might want to try with newer GDB  11.2...